# Cannot import json files with json.load

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-import

I am trying to import json files to python, clean them and save them as csv. My problem is really on *importing* the json files from my computer in order to manipulate them. Something goes wrong in the first lines, the rest of the code works when I import the files directly from an API.

This is the code with the API that works:

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd

myList = {"325413", "424430"}
for toImport in myList:
    query = {"naics": toImport}
    results = requests.post(
        "https://www.lobbyview.org/public/api/reports", data=json.dumps(query)
    )

    json_response = results.json()["result"]

    resulting_data = []

    for data in json_response:
        year = data["year"]
          ....do my staff....


    # create a DataFrame
 b.to_csv(r"path/" +toImport +".csv")
```

And this is the one with the directory that doesn't:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, json

myList = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
for toImport in myList:
    with open("path" + toImport + ".json") as f:
        json_response = json.load(f)

    resulting_data = []

    for data in json_response:
        year = data["year"]
        ....do my staff....

    # create a DataFrame
    b = pd.DataFrame(resulting_data)
    print(b)
    b.to_csv(r"path/" +toImport +".csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, json

myList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
for toImport in myList:
    with open("path/" + toImport + ".json") as f:
        json_response = json.load(f)

    resulting_data = []

    for data in json_response:
        year = data["year"]
        ..do my staff....

    # create a DataFrame
    b = pd.DataFrame(resulting_data)
    print(b)
    b.to_csv(r"path/" +toImport +".csv")
```

Comment: Thanks Dharmveer, I have modified it as you suggested but it still doesn't work.
I have added the code that works with the API in my post.

Comment: (And I have checked the path too)

Comment: Yes I have, but when it is a path mistake I have the error `No such file or directory`.  So I know the path is correct.

Comment: if 1.json is present in the directory and if is not empty then programe should work.